# How to redesign a large image gallery without manually copying and pasting filenames/description into new code

Tags: html, css

I'm currently redesigning a website and the original code was horrible and cluttered. I have to convert their original image gallery to the new layout. More work than I thought.

See: http://dev.collabshot.com/show/323dc7/

This is the crappy code that displays the original:

```
  <div id="new_gallery" style="margin-left: 260px; margin-top: 220px;"><a href="new_gallery.html" style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px;">Check out our new additions!</a></div>

       <div id="e5" style="position:absolute;left:252;top:266;width:203;height:155;"><!--$img %ImageAssetImpl:images/Abednego.JPG$--><img src="images/Abednego.JPG" width="203" height="155" alt=""></div>      <div id="e6" style="position:absolute;left:278;top:435;width:140;height:62;"><span class="text"><b><font color="#CCCCCC"><span style="font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">Abednego &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$3.00<br>McMillian 1972<br> 25&quot; E Evr 6.5&quot;<br soft></span></font></b></span>      </div>

  <div id="e7" style="position:absolute;left:520;top:265;width:161;height:156;"><!--$img %ImageAssetImpl:images/Almond_Puff.JPG$--><img src="images/Almond_Puff.JPG" width="161" height="156" alt=""></div>      <div id="e8" style="position:absolute;left:768;top:262;width:151;height:159;"><!--$img %ImageAssetImpl:images/Angelus_Angel.JPG$--><img src="images/Angelus_Angel.JPG" width="151" height="159" alt=""></div>
```

The new layout I made will display the images somewhat like this (note: i don't have the spacing setup correctly yet): http://dev.collabshot.com/show/7eefa2/

I know I could probably use regex to extract the code I needed and put into a table layout; however, I don't have any experience to come up with a regex to do this. I don't know if it would be the efficient way of going about it tho.

Pretty much just trying to display these images in a grid format with description and pricing below them, that's all.

This is a question for the web designers that have experience running into issues such as this. What would you do to make this as painless as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Dive into external CSS. But really, sometimes web design is a very tedious process.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past in this situation is used a simple jQuery selector to pull out all the markup for the images. Then wrap it up with whatever I need and write that HTML to a div somewhere. Like this:

```
$(function(
    var output = "";

    $('img').each(function(){
       $('some-container').append($(this).html());
    });

)};
```

That should work, but might not get you all the way. You'll still have to clean it up by hand a bit.